# Server returned HTTP status 404 Not Found

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-clique, performance

I am running a local ethereum PoA(clique) network in my windows computer using geth with 2 nodes. I am very new to this.
I am trying to get the performance data of the chain using prometheus.

1. I used the following commands to start node1

geth --datadir .\node1 --port 30306 --bootnodes enode://eb9c64d874a4e78ed66417c28e463f50b1a28d2b3291ef482b6f16c406a6656692cbf7507c036b54bf4a662b9179d5bb0f91910c04c5f0344f16e9b3ca493656@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30305  --networkid 7008 --unlock 0xCCAD7D44F365c7C269Cf1D75F76D185d3d0fbd4c --password .\node1\password.txt --authrpc.port 8551 --mine --miner.etherbase 0xCCAD7D44F365c7C269Cf1D75F76D185d3d0fbd4c --miner.gasprice 0 --syncmode full --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.api admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain "*" --http.vhosts "*" --http.port 8545 --metrics.expensive --pprof --metrics.addr "127.0.0.1" --metrics.port 6060

2. Used the prometheus.yml as follows
   scrape_configs:

- job_name: 'geth_node1_metrics'
  static_configs:

  - targets: ['localhost:6060']

3. Netstat command showed me
   netstat -ano | findstr :6060
   TCP    127.0.0.1:6060         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       17892
   TCP    127.0.0.1:6060         127.0.0.1:53841        ESTABLISHED     17892
   TCP    127.0.0.1:53829        127.0.0.1:6060         TIME_WAIT       0
   TCP    127.0.0.1:53841        127.0.0.1:6060         ESTABLISHED     22496

Can you help me figure out what needs to be done to solve this issue?